# Screen sharing between two android devices

Tags: android, google-cast

I am trying to create an android application that continuously runs in background of one device and keeps sending data to another device. To be precise, the device 1 shares its screen to device 2 continuously. Is there a method to do this on android?

One solution is to share the screenshots of the device 1 continuously but I do not know if it will be very efficient.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the content you want to share.
If it's mostly logic, then you can use push service from A to B, where B rebuild the UI based on the push data.
If it's mostly picture or even video, then it's out of my knowledge.